# File descriptor opened once but closed many times; why the discrepancy?

Tags: linux, shell-script, redirection, file-descriptors

I was trying to use process substitution and come across the following example:

```
exec 3>&1
tar cf /dev/fd/4 $directory_name 4>&1 >&3 3>&- | bzip2 -c > file.tar.bz2 3>&-
exec 3>&-
```

As per my understanding that means the following:

1. Create file descriptor `3` and attach it to stdout.
2. `tar` will compress files in the directory defined by `$directory_name` and compressed file is denoted internally by file descriptor `4`.
3. File descriptor `4` is attached to stdout.
4. stdout is attached to file descriptor `3` and file descriptor `3` closed.

But again in `bzip2` file descriptor is closed again and in final line `exec` command is also closing descriptor `3`. There I am lost, why the same file descriptor is closed 3 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are different descriptors. See [this good answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91061/108618). It says:

> [A child] inherits a copy of the file descriptor. So closing the descriptor in the child will close it for the child, but not the parent, and vice versa.

In a case like `tar cf /dev/fd/4 $directory_name 4>&1 >&3 3>&-` redirections are handled by the shell before `tar` even starts, but the principle is the same: these descriptors are not these of the main shell. When `tar` starts (strictly: when the copy of the shell eventually execs to `tar`), *its* `/dev/fd/*` links are already prepared and there is no `/dev/fd/3`.

In the same way `bzip2` finds *its own* descriptors prepared. They may link to the same files as descriptors of some other process do, but they are separate entities.

Keep in mind each process sees its own descriptors in `/dev/fd/`, it's a useful trick. If you consider `/proc/<PID>/fd/` directories, it will become more clear descriptors are per PID.

Finally `exec 3>&-` closes the descriptor for the main shell. It's yet another separate entity.